# Update only time from my Datetime field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a date 2013-12-14 05:00:00.000 in my table.

Now i want to update only time of that date. E.G to 2013-12-14 04:00:00.000

Is there any query to update only time from datetime field?

Comment: In SQL Server **2008**, it would be a lot easier if you stored the time portion in a `TIME` column separately, if you need to update it separately.

Comment: @marc_s if you were using say an ORM implementation, wouldn't this be quite painful as you'd need a view that concatenated both fields?  This probably isn't related to the question above I'm just curious :)

Comment: You have not included enough information to understand what the problem is. Why can't you just update the value of the column to `2013-12-14 04:00:00.000`? Or do you want to set the time value to 04:00 regardless of what date it is? Or do you want to subtract one hour from the current time or ...?

Comment: i have lot of rows with the same values

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, CAST(CAST(MyDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Or this

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(MyDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: Is not DATEADD anymore, but DATE_ADD

Comment: @MatteoToma it's MS SQL Server related question, not MySQL

Answer (score 12):

User the below one to update the Time only for `datetime` column -

```
select  CONVERT(varchar(10),datecolumn, 120) + ' 12:34:56', 
        CONVERT(varchar(10),datecolumn, 120) + ' 00:00:00', 
        RSLV_LTR_INITIAL_DUE_DT, *
from twhere able1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @Time as TIME;
DECLARE @Date as DATETIME;

SELECT @Time = CONVERT(TIME, '2016-01-01 09:30:00.000');
SELECT @Date = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()); --2017-03-10 16:37:34.403

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, @Time), DATEADD(HH, DATEPART(HOUR, @Time), @Date))
```

**OUTPUT:**
2017-03-10 09:30:00.000

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET DATETIME_FIELD = CAST(CAST(CONVERT(DATE, DATETIME_FIELD,101) AS VARCHAR) + ' 2' + ':' +  '22' AS DATETIME) WHERE (OUR_CONDTTION)
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of just updating a particular part of the datetime you can use `SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS` like:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(MyDate), MONTH(MyDate), DAY(MyDate), <HoursValue>, <MinutesValue>)
```

In other cases it may be required to copy parts of datetime to other or update only certain parts of the datetime:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(MyDate), MONTH(MyDate), DAY(MyDate), DATEPART(hour, MyDate), DATEPART(minute, MyDate))
```

Refer [SQL Server Date/Time related API references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more such functions

Comment: There is also DATETIMEFROMPARTS, that allows to set the second and milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @d datetime;
SELECT @d = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0);

DECLARE @t time(7);
SET @t = CAST('10:10:10' AS time);

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, @d, 101)) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), @t));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this script:

```
declare @curDate datetime=getdate() --or any other datetime 
declare @time time='22:31'
declare @hour int ,@min int
set @hour=datepart(hh,@time)
set @min=datepart(mm,@time)
select @curDate=Dateadd(HOUR,@hour,convert(datetime,convert(Date,@curDate)))
select @curDate=Dateadd(MINUTE,@min,@curDate)
Select @curDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to change the whole time part of the string:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, MyColumn), '04:00:00')
```

Comment: Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: DATEDIFF takes 3 parameters:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Are you sure MyColumn is set to the column name of your table? :)

Comment: yep, still not work, but Yuriy Rozhovetskiy's answer works.

Answer (score -2):

The previous query update only the hour portion but this query will update all portions of the time i.e hour, minutes, seconds:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET DATETIME_FIELD = CONCAT(CAST(DATETIME_FIELD AS Date), ' ', CAST('2016-02-01 09:20:00.0000000' AS TIME))
```

Comment: I hope my edit matches your intent - you'll notice that I copied your explanation from the comment and put the code in a code block. For future reference, you can do this yourself by clicking the 'edit' link beneath your post.