# How to update time value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several datetime entries that I need to replaced the time part with the midnight value - '00:00:00.000'.

How do I update only the time part of a datetime value?  The date needs to be retained.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700355/update-only-time-from-my-datetime-field-in-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to cast to a `date` and then back again:

```
select cast(cast(col as date) as datetime)
```

or

```
update t
    set col = cast(col as date);
```

Comment: +1 but I much prefer the second method (the additional cast would be unnecessary in an update).