# Group by datetime ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I would like to know a way to return the count of events grouped by a datetime range. The interval between start and end is always one day.

For example, the query should return something like:

2014-07-01 15:00:00  |  2014-07-02 15:00:00  | 23

2014-07-02 15:00:00  |  2014-07-03 15:00:00  | 32

2014-07-03 15:00:00  |  2014-07-04 15:00:00  | 2123

2014-07-04 15:00:00  |  2014-07-05 15:00:00  | 231

It might appear only one of the date columns, in the result set, but the logic it's the same.

Tks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `event_time` in a column, then you can determine the interval in which it falls and find the number of events within each interval, as follows:

The logic is that if the hour is >= 15 (starting from 15:00:00), the start_time would be the same day. For `event_time`s before 15:00:00, the start_time would be the previous day. Similarly, if the hour is >= 15 (starting from 15:00:00), the end_time would be the next day. For `event_time`s before 15:00:00, the end_time would be the current day.

```
select 
CASE 
  when DATEPART(hh, event_time) >= 15 then DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
  else DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))
END START_TIME,
CASE 
  when DATEPART(hh, event_time) >= 15 then DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))
  else DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
END END_TIME,
count(*) no_of_events
FROM events e
group by 
CASE 
  when DATEPART(hh, event_time) >= 15 then DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
  else DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))
END,
CASE 
  when DATEPART(hh, event_time) >= 15 then DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME)))
  else DATEADD(HOUR, 15, CAST(CAST(event_time AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
END;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fd6f/11)</kbd>

**References**:

[Update only time from my Datetime field in sql on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700355/update-only-time-from-my-datetime-field-in-sql)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question!

I'm assuming you have a single date/time in the table and want to provide a starting and ending date/time values as parameters.  I can't compile against SQL Server where I am right now, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (day, start_date, event_time) as period, 
       COUNT (event_time) as event_count
WHERE event_time >= @start_time
  AND event_time <= @end_time
GROUP BY DATEDIFF (day, @start_time, event_time)
```

If you want to display the starting and ending times for each period, create new computed columns in the select statement by adding the DATEDIFF value to @start_time and @end_time.

Comment: For example, I'm trying to get the login counts, on my database, for a period of month and I want to count them in periods of one day, since 7AM to 7AM of the next day. I've tried this way:

SELECT DATEDIFF (day, '2014-06-04 07:00:00.000') as period, 
       COUNT (fl.id) as event_count
FROM FACTLOGIN fl
WHERE fl.datetime >= '2014-06-04 07:00:00.000'
  AND fl.datetime <= '2014-07-04 07:00:00.000'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF (day, '2014-06-04 07:00:00.000', fl.datetime)

Error: 
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]The datediff function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: Sorry, I left the event_time off the first DATEDIFF call in my example.  I corrected it above.  Your code would need to be like this:  SELECT DATEDIFF (day, '2014-06-04 07:00:00.000', fl.datetime) as period, COUNT (fl.id) as event_count FROM FACTLOGIN fl WHERE fl.datetime >= '2014-06-04 07:00:00.000' AND fl.datetime <= '2014-07-04 07:00:00.000' GROUP BY DATEDIFF (day, '2014-06-04 07:00:00.000', fl.datetime)