# Update query to find and change portion of MS SQL DateTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have various datetime stamps on a expiration field (datetime). The datetime in that field for each record varies. For example,

```
2015-12-31 04:59:00:000, 2014-12-31 17:00:00:000, 2020-12-15 04:00:00:000
```

Trying to write a query to find all datetime that have an ENDING that is not equal != to 05:00:00:000.

Then an update query to update the end of the stamp to 05:00:00:000, leaving the front as is.

Some example changes, from - to:

From:

```
2015-12-31 04:59:00:000, 2014-12-31 17:00:00:000, 2020-12-15 04:00:00:000
```

To:

```
2015-12-31 05:00:00:000, 2014-12-31 05:00:00:000, 2020-12-15 05:00:00:000
```

Here is what I'd like to see:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET table_name.expire_field = keep_front_date_portion + '05:00:00.000'
WHERE table_name.expire_field = date_portion_ignore and time_portion != '05:00:00.000'
```

Not sure how this would be written correctly in MS SQL 2008 syntax?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700355/update-only-time-from-my-datetime-field-in-sql) but from what I can tell it needs a timestamp that does not vary.

Comment: `where cast(fld as time) != '05:00:00'` to detect the time, then the linked answer (which does add arbitrary hours to any datetime as the cast to date zeros the time (add 5))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` to reset just the time portion of a datetime value

```
UPDATE table_name
SET expire_field = 
   DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',expire_field),'1900-01-01T05:00:00')
WHERE DATEPART(hour,expire_field) != 5 or
      DATEPART(minute,expire_field) != 0 or
      DATEPART(second,expire_field) != 0
```

But you may find it easier to just skip the `WHERE` clause and let it update the entire table - you're not going to be able to benefit from indexes here anyway.

In the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair, the date is arbitrary. First, the inner `DATEDIFF` asks "how many whole days have passed since `some date`", and then the `DATEADD` adds that same number of days onto `some date at 5am`.

Comment: Initially I did not understand what the 19000101 was, thought it was a code but then discovered that it is an arbitrary anchor date of yyyymmdd that i could actually change to a different yyyymmdd if i wanted. Then it looks at the offset from the next date of 1900-01-01 in the code. But what about the T in 1900-01-01T05:00:00? I tried it without and it worked fine. But if I insert another character 'x' it does not work. I assume the T stands for Time. I see no mention of this T in the docs for DATEDIFF?

Comment: @mann - yes, `T` is a separator for ISO-8601 formatted dates. SQL Server will accept space as a separator but, in some circumstances, may then decide to interpret the string as `yyyy-dd-mm hh:MM:ss` (day and month swapped around), so I'm in the habit of using the `T` separator (which doesn't suffer the same problems) if I'm specifying a date and a time.